# Multiple server side experiments with Google Optimize and GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

I was wondering if it's possible to set up multiple server side experiments using Google Optimize and Google Tag Manager. We followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/52157837/12936081 and it seems to be working just fine with the values sent from the data layer, but given the Analytics variable names (expId and expVar) it feels like we can only do that for one experiment at any given time.

Comment: Any luck? I'm pondering the exact same thing.

Comment: We encoutered the same problem. Since the TGM GA tag does not allow you to set the same setting (expId and expvar) multiple times, I think there is no way to do it with the TGM GA tag :(
Probably we need to create manually the GA/TGM integration with custom JS tag.

Comment: I think I found something that works, give my answer a shot

Answer (score 4):

Instead of sending a separate `expId` and `expVar` with the Google Analytics - Universal Analytics `Pageview`, set `exp` instead to contain both, and separate multiple experiments by `!`.

Combine that with info found in the referenced SO question and in the official docs, and we have `.` to separate the experiment ID and the experiment variants, and `-` to separate any variants in a multivariate test.

For example, if you're submitting experiment ID A (much longer in real life) with variant index 1 (the first non-control variant), and experiment ID B with variant 0 (the control) in the first section, and variant 2 (the second non-control variant) for the second section, you'd set `exp` to `A.1!B.0-2`.

**Setting up the data layer**

If you're creating a test server side, there's no need to resort to any JavaScript in GTM. Simply set up the `dataLayer` with the `exp` variable set, then create a variable that references that from the `dataLayer` in GTM. I found that even though GTM and the Google Analytics Pageview hit run asynchronously, I had to set by data early enough for the GA to pick it up. You could add a separate script tag for this anywhere, or add it to the GTM snippet itself if that's easy to modify. In my case, I just injected this to the end of the `<head>` via a Cloudflare Worker using `HTMLRewriter`, since my test is implemented at the edge.

```
<script>var dataLayer=dataLayer||[];dataLayer.push({"exp":"A.1!B.0-2"})</script>
```

**How I determined this**

I found this format by temporarily adding the client-side Google Optimize JavaScript, and launching two concurrent experiments, and then looking at the network request being sent. I've tested this briefly on a dev instance and data seems to come in.